# Writing bash function as one-line alias

Tags: bash, alias

How do I write this as an alias?

```
p() {
    DIR=~/projects/$@
    pushd "$DIR"
}
```

This is as far as I got, but it's piping stdin to pushd instead of xargs:

```
alias p="xargs printf ~/projects/%s | pushd"
```

It's probably better as a function, but I feel like I would learn something by knowing how to write it on one line and get the piping correct.

Comment: I think you can't do this in an alias.

Comment: Why does it need to be aliased? Give the function the name you want to call and use it as it is. Aliases don't take args.

Comment: As mentioned, it doesn't *need* to be aliased. I'm always looking to learn and expand my understanding, so I'd rather ask than not. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @AndreasWiese comments, you can't do this with an alias. Aliases tack on arguments space-separated, so you can't join them (in a simple way) to the aliased command.

A comment on your function: Why are you using `$@`? You should use `$1` instead. If you call your function with multiple arguments (`p a b c`), you'll probably get <strike>an error (`b: command not found`)</strike> an unknown directory.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. I will look up $@ vs $1 because I didn't understand the difference before.

Comment: Start here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters